# How can I split date range into months

Tags: c#

Now I get many  date range data(DataTable) like this:

startDate:  endDate:

2016-06-12  2016-08-13

2016-01-12  2016-03-13

...

How can I sum total days in each month in this year?
From January to November.

```
        DataTable dtDateRange = ds1.Tables[0];
        //Create Months
        int[] count = new int[12];
        //loop data
        for (int i = 0; i < dtDateRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime startTime = ((DateTime)dtDateRange.Rows[i]["STARTDATE"]);
            DateTime endTime = ((DateTime)dtDateRange.Rows[i]["ENDDATE"]);

            for (int a = startTime.DayOfYear; a < endTime.DayOfYear; a++)
            {
                count[startTime.Month-1] = count[startTime.Month-1] + 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (int c in count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean... do you want to basically maintain 12 counts (assuming you'd normally go up to December) and update those counts based on each range? Have you tried anything yet? How far did you get?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Really not sure I understand. Are you saying you want something like 18 for June, 31 for July and 13 for August using your first date range?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes!I want get 12 count base on those date range.

Comment: "Yes!! want" doesn't really answer the very important part of Jon's comment, "Have you tried anything yet?". Please do some research first and see if you get stuck. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @sr28 sorry,I didn't finish that reply and it was send...
My thoughts:
1.get the lastday of startDate's month.
2.get the firstday of endDate' month.

Comment: @Puz, ok, so what code have you tried to write to try and achieve this?

Comment: @sr28 loop the months in this year create 12 months .Then  update by loop each date range.Are there another better way？Because I got 10K
datarow like those.My English is not good and this is my first ask quation in this website. I am afraid that does not share with you well ..

Comment: Please show your existing code *in the question*. I suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ very carefully, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK,I'll read it.Thank for your patient anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. I've written in it notepad so I'm not sure will it compile. Maybe you'll need a fix here and there. You can use a List to add dates from the for loop to the container, if you want.

```
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-06-12");
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-13");

        for(DateTime date = startDate, startDate <= endDate, date = date.AddMonths(1) )
            Console.WriteLine(date);
```

And if you need only the month of particular date you can just ask it from that date via [Month](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-month) property.

Comment: That was Instructive.thx

Comment: I think the condition in the `for` loop needs to use `date` instead of `startDate`, otherwise it will never end. Also, commas should be semi-colons in the `for` clause.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
           DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Parse("2016-06-12");
            DateTime endDate1 = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-13");
            int days1 = endDate1.Subtract(startDate1).Days;

            DateTime startDate2 = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-12");
            DateTime endDate2 = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-13");
            int days2 = endDate1.Subtract(startDate1).Days;
```